# HTTP request from extension

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a request from my chrome extension to my server.
Let's say that i have the extension installed and i want my server to know that i entered a website. So i get the domain of the current page with the extension and i send it to my server.

My question is... Can the domain owner read my request that i made to my server?

I have succeded in sending the request and receiving the response in my extension, but i don't know if the domain owner can intercept my request.

Comment: Not if you do it in the background script (service worker).